# QUERY [thread1] malformed UTF-8 character sequence at offset 30113337

Tags: mongodb

```
 while importing data in mongodb from js file following error occur.
```

I am using mongo cell 
      [thread1] malformed UTF-8 character sequence at offset 30113337

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the non-ASCII characters while running script from js file.